# Find rows from table A without record in joined table B

Tags: sql-server, performance, database-performance, query-performance

I have two tables called Employee (columns: Id, Name) and DataSource (columns: Id, EmployeeId, DataSourceName).

Each employee can be exported to zero or multiple datasources and imagine following situation:

Employee table

```
+----+-------------+
| Id | Name        |
+----+-------------+
| 1  | Ivan        |
| 2  | Adam        |
+----+-------------+
```

DataSource table:

```
+----+---------------------------------+
| Id | EmplpoyeeId   | DataSourceName  |
+----+---------------------------------+
| 1  | 1             | Source1         |
| 2  | 1             | Source2         |
| 3  | 2             | Source2         |
+----+---------------------------------+
```

I need a query to determine which employee is not exported to 'Source1' (the result should be 'Adam' in this case as he is exported to 'Source2' only).

Tables Employee and DataSource can have large amount of records (thousands).

There are a few techniques to determine it and we need to find the one with best performance. There are few which came to my mind:

Left JOIN:

```
SELECT Employee.Id 
FROM Employee 
LEFT JOIN DataSource ON DataSource.EmployeeId = Employee.Id AND DataSource.DataSourceName = 'Source1'
WHERE DataSource.Id IS NULL
```

INNER SELECT:

```
SELECT Employee.Id
FROM Employee
WHERE NOT EXIST (SELECT NULL FROM DataSource WHERE DataSource.EmployeeId = Employee.Id AND DataSource.DataSourceName = 'Source1')
```

EXCEPTION:

```
SELECT Employee.ID 
FROM Employee

EXCEPT

SELECT Employee.Id 
FROM Employee 
INNER JOIN DataSource ON DataSource.EmployeeId = Employee.Id AND DataSource.DataSourceName = 'Source1'
```

Before starting benchmarking them I'd like to ask whether there are more ways which I should take into account (and might perform well). Could you please share your ideas for the best performant query.

Comment: You must just test, however the WHERE NOT EXISTS "should" be quicker, since it doesn't need to do the full join and can exit early... but this will depend on a number of factors so you really need to just test

Comment: I think so, we also can exit after first record is found (by using SELECT TOP 1) - this might also play for WHERE NOT EXISTS

Comment: If you are using a select in a NOT EXIST (), you dont need to use TOP 1, it will automatically stop after it finds one record

Comment: I mean using TOP 1 in top query not in nested one so it states: SELECT TOP 1 Employee.Id
FROM Employee
WHERE NOT EXIST ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you require further reading on the subject this article is good;

http://www.sqlinthewild.co.za/index.php/2010/03/23/left-outer-join-vs-not-exists/

It suggests that the NOT EXISTS will perform better as it doesn't need to complete the full join (does an Anti-Semi join instead of a Semi Join);

"That’s the major difference between these two. When using the LEFT OUTER JOIN … IS NULL technique, SQL can’t tell that you’re only doing a check for nonexistance. Optimiser’s not smart enough (yet). Hence it does the complete join and then filters. The NOT EXISTS filters as part of the join."

Comment: thanks @Milney I am also wondering about the 3rd option - exception, i have added it to my question. What do you think about this one?

Comment: @jabko87 - This is actually logically different - for example, EXCEPT will filter out duplicates (as though you had applied DISTINCT) since it is a set based operation, it will also treat NULLs as values if you have them. So you may use except but will have to consider if it is actually doing the same thing.. I don't think it will be faster though (because again - it has to process the whole result set) so I would go with NOT EXISTS. But the only way to know for sure (with your specific data profile) is to TEST! Just run both a few times, and measure the difference (use SET STATISTICS TIME ON)

Comment: @jabko87 The most important thing for performance will be having an INDEX on the columns (EmployeeId and DataSourceName) with up to date statistics... If you have that, they should all perform acceptibly